# .NET Framework 3.0 ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, prerequisites

**How can I specify .NET Framework 3.0 (without SP2) as a prerequisite?  I can't seem find the bootstrapper package anywhere.**

I've built an app that uses .NET Framework 3.0.  I'm deploying it using ClickOnce.

I've set the prerequisite to ".NET Framework 3.0 SP2" (after having downloaded the bootstrapper package [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb898654.aspx), which added the option for me to choose this prerequisite in Visual Studio)

When installing my app on Windows Vista, I get this error:

"The version of the .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 can not be installed on Vista....Install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1..."

I purposely targeted .NET Framework 3.0 so that Vista users could use my app without an additional Framework download (it's my understanding that Vista ships with .NET Framework 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of that particular bootstrapper.

In the Limitations section of the link you provided, it states

> These packages provide support for x86 and x64 operating systems,
>   however they do not support and will fail to install on Windows Vista
>   or subsequent operating systems. To provide a prerequisite that will
>   install on Windows Vista, use the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper
>   package instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb898654.aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks, I discovered this after I implemented it. My question still stands: how to I specify .NET Framework 3.0 (without SP2) as a prerequisite?  I don't want my Vista users to be forced to download .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Comment: gotcha, hrm that's an interesting one.  3.0 SP2 wasn't provided as a "framework version" like 3.5 SP1, so not sure if you can.  I'll do some research